# aws codebuild for windows 2019 failed with .net 4.7 project

Tags: .net, windows, aws-codebuild

I am trying to build my .Net 4.7 project using AWS CodeBuild Windows Server 2019.

MS Build:

```
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.9.21.664' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\bin'.
```

The error : Missing Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.dll

```
API.csproj : error MSB4247: Could not load SDK Resolver. A manifest file exists, but the path to the SDK Resolver DLL file could not be found. Manifest file path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\bin\SdkResolvers\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.xml'. SDK resolver path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.dll
```

Looks like  folder `Common7` is missing from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual  Studio\2017\BuildTools`.

From my computer, folder `BuildTools` is under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017`

Any idea pls?

Also how to install MSBuild 2019 instead of default MSBuild 2017 into AWS CodeBuild please?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like AWS codeBuild image doent have enough tools for building my .net 4.7 project. It is very straight forward with AzureDevOps pipelines. A win for Azure.